# to pass more than one parameters

Tags: jquery, ajax

i pass on one parameter to my php code it works fine but i want to pass another parameter
to the same code but not helping, below is my code

ctr is the parameter i am passing to create dynamic rows

```
function addrows() 
{
  var ctr = $('#items').val();
  var cmbgrp = $('#cmbgrp').val();
  $.post('open_row_add.php', {ctr: ctr}, function(data) 
  {
    $(data).appendTo('#data');
    ctr++;
    $('#items').val(ctr);
   });
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP. Pass more parameters like this: `{ctr : ctr, alt : alt, etc : etc}`

Comment: so, `{ctr:ctr, param2:param2, etc...}`. it's not rocket science...

Comment: {ctr: ctr, cmbgrp: cbmgrp}

Comment: Here's an example: `$.post( "test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } );`  See the documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: Dude, please check documentation before asking questions like this.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
$.post('open_row_add.php', 
       {
        ctr: ctr, 
        cmbgrp :cmbgrp 
       }, 
        function(data) 
        {
         $(data).appendTo('#data');
         ctr++;
         $('#items').val(ctr);
 });
```